# Scipy minimize: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 10), indices imply (1, 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, minimization

I am doing a mean-variance portfolio optimization exercise and I am stuck with the error mentioned in the title. The goal of my optimization is to maximize the sharpe ratio of a portfolio of 10 assets with an additional tracking error constrains.

For tracking-error portfolio, the benchmark is an equal-weighted portfolio of the 10 funds (in each sheet). The tracking error is defined as the standard deviation of the difference between the returns of your portfolio and the benchmark. In this project, we require the annual tracking error to be not greater than 5%. See picture of constraint formula:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd

# importing the data 
data_ff = pd.read_excel(r'path\Project_2.xlsx', 'Fama-French Factor', parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
data_mf = pd.read_excel(r'path\Project_2.xlsx', 'Mutual Fund', parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
data_sb = pd.read_excel(r'path\Project_2.xlsx', 'SmartBeta', parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
data_hf = pd.read_excel(r'path\Project_2.xlsx', 'Hedge Fund Index', parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")
data_ff.rename(columns={'dateff':'Date'}, inplace = True)

# in-sample period
data_ff = data_ff[data_ff.index>=200101].dropna()
data_ff = data_ff[data_ff.index<=201212].dropna()
data_mf = data_mf[data_mf.index>=200101].dropna()
data_mf = data_mf[data_mf.index<=201212].dropna()
data_sb = data_sb[data_sb.index>=200101].dropna()
data_sb = data_sb[data_sb.index<=201212].dropna()
data_hf = data_hf[data_hf.index>=200101].dropna()
data_hf = data_hf[data_hf.index<=201212].dropna()

mf_cov_mat = data_mf.cov()*(12)
mf_mu = data_mf.mean()*12
sb_cov_mat = data_sb.cov()*(12)
sb_mu = data_sb.mean()*12
hf_cov_mat = data_hf.cov()*(12)
hf_mu = data_hf.mean()*12

weight_MVP_mf = pd.DataFrame(index = mf_mu.index)
weight_MVP_sb = pd.DataFrame(index = sb_mu.index)
weight_MVP_hf = pd.DataFrame(index = hf_mu.index)
results_MVP_mf = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,4)), index = ('sharpe','return','volatility'),
                              columns = ('long-only','long-short','error-tracking','factor-neutral'))
results_MVP_sb = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,4)), index = ('sharpe','return','volatility'),
                              columns = ('long-only','long-short','error-tracking','factor-neutral'))
results_MVP_hf = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,4)), index = ('sharpe','return','volatility'),
                              columns = ('long-only','long-short','error-tracking','factor-neutral'))


for df in (data_mf, data_sb, data_hf):
    # return vector and var-cov matrix
    df_mu = pd.Series.to_frame(df.mean()*12)
    df_cov = df.cov()

    eq_weight = pd.DataFrame(np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]))

    # sharpe ratio
    def objective_df(x):
        risk_free = data_ff['rf'].iloc[-1]
        df_port_mu = np.dot(df_mu.T, x)
        df_port_stdev = np.sqrt(np.dot(np.dot(x.T,df_cov),x))*np.sqrt(12)
        return -df_port_mu/df_port_stdev


    # total weight = 100%
    def constraint1(x):
        return x.sum()-1

    # tracking error 
    def constraint2(x):
        y = x-eq_weight
        z = float(np.sqrt(np.dot(np.dot(y.T,df_cov),y))*np.sqrt(12)-0.05)
        return z

    x0 = eq_weight1
    b = (0,1)
    bnds = (b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b)
    cons1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1}
    cons2 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2}
    cons = [cons1,cons2]

    sol = minimize(objective_df, x0, method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
    print (sol.fun)
```

The error message I get seems to be coming from constraint 2. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Show full error and traceback

Comment: Why is there a `float(...)` in `constraint2`?

Comment: I don't think you should be passing a dataframe as `x0`.  It should be a simple numpy array.  `scipy` is written with `numpy`.  `pandas` inputs only work to the extent that conversions like `np.asarray(pandas_object)` works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @hpaulj. I removed the float in constraint2 and it didnt seem to affect the code. I also changed x0 to a numpy array but I still get an error message: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 10), indices imply (1, 10)